# Every 30 minutes the number of instances on my appengine application skyrocket. Why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

Tags: google-app-engine

My appengine-web.xml is configured to have everything automatic. Max concurrent requests is set to 4, and the application is set to multithreaded mode, if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Assuming the logs don't show a burst of requests at those times, do you have a `cron.xml` that's scheduling work during those peaks?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith No actually. I do have cron jobs but they'd each only issue a single request. Some every minute, some every 10 minutes, some every few hours. It doesn't appear to be related to cron. And yes, the logs don't show a burst of requests there.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the answer was to STOP using "automatic" all over the place. No only have I significantly reduced wasteful instance startups, but overall my app is performing better and costing way less even without the weird instance startup explosions.

For what it's worth, here are the settings I ended up going with:

```
<instance-class>F1</instance-class>
<automatic-scaling>
    <min-idle-instances>0</min-idle-instances> 
    <max-idle-instances>1</max-idle-instances> 
    <min-pending-latency>100ms</min-pending-latency>
    <max-pending-latency>15000ms</max-pending-latency>
    <max-concurrent-requests>3</max-concurrent-requests>
</automatic-scaling>
```

All my users are quite happy with the change and the application is running very consistently now.